# Is there a way to manually trigger Safari 5's extension update check?

Tags: safari-extension

When developing Safari extensions, I'd like to be able to manually trigger an update check to ensure that my update.plist is correctly formatted and accessible. Has anyone found a way to do this? I haven't even been able to determine the standard update check interval.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can force an update check by:

1. Opening Safari's Preferences
2. Selecting the Extension's Preference Pane
3. Clicking the "Updates" list item along the left hand side.

This will force an update check of all extensions you have installed.

Comment: Can confirm that this works, even though Safari doesn't give any indication that it's performing the check. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure this still works? I tried and my extension doesn't update, I also monitored with Fiddler and can't see any connections/requests done by Safari when click on Updates